# if $\mathbb{S}$is any non empty set , why $ \varnothing- \mathbb{S} =\varnothing $ is true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i can't understand why ?

> if   $\mathbb{S}$ is any set , why   $  \varnothing- \mathbb{S} 
>  =\varnothing  $  is true .

and does is hold for **$  \varnothing- \varnothing   =\varnothing  $** ??

i know that for any two sets $ \mathbb{A,B}$ that $\mathbb{A-B}=  \begin{Bmatrix}
x:x\in \mathbb{A}  , x   \notin \mathbb{B}  
\end{Bmatrix}$

thanks for advance .

Comment: From the first condition in the dfn of $\mathbb{A}-\mathbb{B}$, what elements could be in $\varnothing-\mathbb{S}$?

Comment: since $\varnothing$ is an emptyset with no elements in it the results hold good

Comment: What does this notation mean? Hint: it is the intersection of 2 sets.

Comment: @Eoin: In modern set theory, the complement of a set is *not* a set; only "relative" complement (which is defined as the set difference) is a set. So your answer, while perhaps helpful in the most naive way, is ultimately not as helpful.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I suppose so. I asummed it is the relative complement of some intuitive set. While not true, as you have pointed out, in most other subjects it tends to suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that $A-B=\{a\in A\mid a\notin B\}$.

So $\varnothing - S=\{a\in\varnothing\mid a\notin S\}$. If $a\in\varnothing-S$, then what thing happens?

Comment: so there is no elements in phi xD i feel dull about it

Comment: Wait until you hear that $\phi$ is a Greek letter, and $\varnothing$ is derived from a Nordic letter! (So it's definitely not phi!) :-)

Comment: :O so we dont call the empty set phi ?

Comment: Not when we don't want to be wrong! :-)

Comment: thank you ! my life saver ,tbh its the first time i know this , i would like learn more from you  , so we only call it empty set or there is other name ?

Comment: Mostly just "the empty set". Something "nothing" or "zero" (depending on the context).

Comment: thank u again ! and also thank you to explain why complements dont work :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: now can i say  the empty set is the identity set ?

Comment: I wouldn't say that. It sounds strange, and "the identity function" which is a set, is not empty (in most cases).

Answer (score 8):

There is no $x\in \varnothing$, so there is no $x$ such that $x\in \varnothing$ and $x\not\in S$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do it in a funny way: for every set $\mathrm X$, it is true that $\emptyset \subset \mathrm X$.

So for every set $\mathrm S$, we have $\emptyset \subset \mathrm X =\emptyset - \mathrm S$.

Now, we also have $\mathrm A - \mathrm B \subset A$ so, $\emptyset - \mathrm S \subset \emptyset$.

By double inclusion, $\emptyset - \mathrm S = \emptyset$.

Comment: i got it ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that $A - B = A \cap B'$ And substitute $A = \varnothing, B = S$. And you're done!

Comment: great ! i can see it now ,thank you :)

Comment: See my comment to user62498.

Comment: i saw it , now i understand what u said  fully @AsafKaragila

Answer (score 1):

Since $A-B \subseteq A$, we have $\varnothing- \mathbb{S} \subseteq \varnothing$, which implies $\varnothing- \mathbb{S} =\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

Asaf has said it perfectly.  Another notation used here that would be the same as $A - B$ is $A \setminus B$.  This can sometimes help eliminate the idea that we are "subtracting" anything, but rather *removing* elements of $B$ from the set $A$.  Thus, trying to remove anything from an already empty set, $ \emptyset $, always results in the empty set again.  So, both $\emptyset \setminus A = \emptyset$ and  $\emptyset \setminus \emptyset = \emptyset$ are true, where $ A \neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$  \varnothing- \mathbb{S} 
 =\varnothing\cap S^{c}=\varnothing  $

Comment: In modern set theory, complements are not sets. Only relative complements (which are defined by set difference).